# coffescript jquery on click delegated function rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have question, i have input `event_dodavatel`, on that field is on keyup  declared loading of json. But i can't click on div with id `doplnovac`.

Can anybody give me hints?

html:

```
<input type="text" name="event[dodavatel]" id="event_dodavatel" />
<textarea name="event[adresa]" id="event_adresa"></textarea>
```

fragment of generated autocomplete:

```
<div id="help">
<div id="napoveda" class="list-group sm">
<div class="doplnovac" id="14" data-name="Vitana a.s.                 +" data-adresa="Mělnická 133" data-city="Byšice">Vitana a.s.                 +</div>
<div class="doplnovac" id="4751" data-name="Vitana,a.s. - catering" data-adresa="Mělnická 133" data-city="Byšice">Vitana,a.s. - catering</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CoffeScript

```
String::replaceAll = (stringFind, stringReplace) ->
ex = new RegExp(stringFind.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, 
'\\$1'), 'g')
@replace ex, stringReplace

jQuery ->
  $(document).on "click", ".doplnovac",(event) ->
    $('#event_dodavatel').val $this.data('name')
    $('#event_adresadodavatel').val $this.data('adresa') + ' ' + $this.data('city')
    $('#help').empty()
    event.preventdefault()
    return
  $('#event_dodavatel').keyup ->
  $('#help').empty()
  $.getJSON 'local web/'+$(this).val(), (data) ->
    items=[]
    $.each data.data, (i, item) ->
      items.push("<div class='doplnovac' id='"+item.Internal+"' data-name='"+item.Name1+"' data-adresa='"+item.Street+"' data-city='"+item.City+"'>" +item.Name1+ "</div>");
    $('<div>',
      'id': 'napoveda'
      'class': 'list-group sm'
      html: items.join('')).appendTo '#help'
  return
return
$('.kalendar').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: 
$.datepicker.noWeekends,defaultDate: new Date() });
$('#q_datum_eq').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: 
$.datepicker.noWeekends,defaultDate: new Date() });
$('#q_datum_eq').change ->
@form.submit()
return
$('#q_cil_id_eq').change ->
@form.submit();
return
$('#tisk').click ->
window.print()
return
```

Comment: Can you add your div html too? And if there any css applied on that div

Comment: Hi i am update my question for generated div doplnovac

Comment: Your html says more than one item is sharing same id `doplnovac`, that's the reason, your click may not work.

Comment: ok well i am send autocomplete  so i am generate group of three or four  items with same id i put in id part of primary key

Comment: Element IDs should be unique within the entire document.

Comment: Well `id` is suppose to uniquely identified elements in your document. You cannot use duplicated `ids`. You can use `class` to group elements. You can assign same class name to elements to group them.

Comment: how to catch   on cofffescript id="doplnovac-various ids  i am sorry but still new in some part Ty  for advices

Comment: Give try to below given code. Its always better to use  class. What do you mean by catch?

Comment: when you click  on  div #doplnovac i am copy from that div property data-name  to input with 
 id event_dodavatel and  from  data-adresa and data city to input  #event_adresadodavatel

Comment: That you can do with class too. `$(this)` will refer to the element you click.

Comment: idea something like this $(document).on "click", "[id^=doplnovac]",(event) ->
      $('#event_dodavatel').val $this.data('name')
      $('#event_adresadodavatel').val $this.data('adresa') + ' ' + $this.data('city')
      $('#help').empty()
      event.preventdefault()
      return

Comment: I am still not sure why you are avoiding class

Comment: i am updated to use class doplnovac in id of element i have just primary id. still no catch on click

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div id="help">
  <div id="napoveda" class="list-group sm">
   <div class="list-group-item doplnovac" data-name="Vitana a.s.                 +" data-adresa="Mělnická 133" data-city="Byšice">Vitana a.s.                 +</div>
   <div class="list-group-item doplnovac" data-name="Vitana,a.s. - catering" data-adresa="Mělnická 133" data-city="Byšice">Vitana,a.s. - catering</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
jQuery ->
  $(document).on "click", ".doplnovac",(event) ->
    $('#event_dodavatel').val $this.data('name')
    $('#event_adresadodavatel').val $this.data('adresa') + ' ' + $this.data('city')
    $('#help').empty()
    event.preventdefault()
    return
  $('#event_dodavatel').keyup ->
  $('#help').empty()
  $.getJSON 'local web/'+$(this).val(), (data) ->
    items=[]
    $.each data.data, (i, item) ->
      items.push("<div class='list-group-item doplnovac' data-name='"+item.Name1+"' data-adresa='"+item.Street+"' data-city='"+item.City+"'>" +item.Name1+ "</div>");
    $('<div>',
      'id': 'napoveda'
      'class': 'list-group sm'
      html: items.join('')).appendTo '#help'
  return
return
```

Comment: wel i a updated my question  with usage of class  but still cant  click  anyway thanks for all ideas